# How to convert a RGB tiff into pseudocolor with GDAL etc?

Tags: qgis, gdal, osx

In QGIS I have made a singleband pseudocolor image out of one of the bands from a RGB GeoTiff. I choose one band and then make a linear color interpolation (see attached image).

[image: screen shot from QGIS]

I now want to do the same thing the command line way (GDAL/Mapnik/etc) so I can get a workflow going, but I don't really know where to start?

My idea is to split the RGB image into three greyscale files for each band and then give each band a pseudocolor map. Any ideas of how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I figured it out!

1. `gdal_translate -b 2 input_rgb.tiff output_green.tiff`
2. `gdaldem color-relief output_green.tiff green_colortable.txt output_green_rgb.tiff` taking the colortable from QGIS.

I did this for both red and green bands. After that I combined them by using Mapnik!